# How to make Google map info window's tail or tip shorter

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing Google maps using JavaScript. How can I make Google map info window's tail or tip shorter as it is somewhat longer. Please provide any example links if any.

Answer (score 0):

you can use infobox rather than infowindow. Following library is extension to the infowindow

" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js">"

Also you can use below url for api reference

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html